# AWS CloudWatch Cron Expression Schedule Not Firing Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

So I have set up a Lambda function that shuts down a couple of my Instances in AWS. I am trying to set up a CloudWatch rule that fires the function every night at 11.59pm.

I am using the Cron expression: 59 11 * * ? *

Everything looks to be set up but nothing happens in the EC2 Dashboard and the instance does not shutdown. I have run tests on the function and it works fine not sure where to start and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cron expression for 23:59 PM or (11:59 PM in 12 hours clock) would this if I'm not wrong. It may be the issue here:

```
59 23 * * ? *
```

Comment: Yeah, good spot. I had been changing my Cron expressions around so I got myself confused. But I was doing a test with a cron expression such as 17:30 ect.. and waited until that time and the Lambda would not fire.

Comment: What do you see in cloudwatch events on Lambda console? And what's your input to Lambda function looks like if there's any.